# PyQt - Create a function that draws something with parameters provided

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qpainter

I am working on a project that I need to draw, for example, a rectangle every time the `QPushButton` is pressed using `QPainter`. This is the first problem, the second one here is that I need some information to be sent to the drawing function too, for example, a list containing tuples, each tuple has 4 elements: `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` - the locations of top-left and right-down point (aka. the function is able to draw multiple rectangles).

So, how do I implement it? or use anything other than `QPainter` but can do thing like that is also good.

Comment: Maybe use a `QFrame` with a visible border?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.